# React ref.current is undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

i have page with some data on it, and an abort button. Clicking on this abort button shows a
Modal with 2 buttons, asking the users to either cancel or confirm.

What I am having trouble is detecting clicks outside this Modal. Here is what I have tried :

```
const BenefInputHome = ({ requests }) => {
    const [showCancelModal, setShowCancelModal] = useState(false);
    const {requestAbortInput} = requests;
    
    const cancelModal = showCancelModal && (
        <CancelModal isVisible onClose={() => setShowCancelModal(false)} onConfirm={requestAbortInput} />
    )
    
    const onCancel = useCallback(() => {
        setShowCancelModal(true);
    }, []);
    
    return (
        <>
            {cancelModal}
            <button onClick={onCancel}>ABORT</button>
        </>
    );
}


const CancelModal = ({ isVisible, onClose, onConfirm }) => {
    const ref = useRef();
    
    useEffect(() => {
        window.onclick = (event) => {
            if (event.target.contains(ref.current) && event.target !== ref.current) {
                console.log('outside');
            } else {
                console.log('inside');
            }
        }
    }, []);
    
    return (
        <Modal visible={isVisible} onCancel={onClose}>
            <div ref={ref}>
                <Message
                    extra={
                        <GridRow>
                            <GridCol>
                                <buttton onClick={onClose}>Cancel</button>
                            </GridCol>
                            <GridCol>
                                <buttton onClick={onConfirm}>Confirm</button>
                            </GridCol>
                        </GridRow>
                    }
                />
            </div>
        </Modal>
    );
}
```

It turns out `ref.current` is always undefined. How can I make `ref.current` not undefined ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with your code is that the ref is not assigned to an element that you want to check for clicks on. Here's how you can fix it:

```
const CancelModal = ({ isVisible, onClose, onConfirm }) => {
    const ref = useRef(); // Create a ref for the modal container
    
    useEffect(() => {
        const handleClickOutside = (event) => {
            if (ref.current && !ref.current.contains(event.target)) {
                console.log('outside');
            } else {
                console.log('inside');
            }
        };

        // Add a click event listener to the document
        document.addEventListener('click', handleClickOutside);

        // Remove the event listener when the component unmounts
        return () => {
            document.removeEventListener('click', handleClickOutside);
        };
    }, [onClose]);

    return (
        <Modal visible={isVisible} onCancel={onClose}>
            <div ref={ref}>
                <Message
                    extra={
                        <GridRow>
                            <GridCol>
                                <button onClick={onClose}>Cancel</button>
                            </GridCol>
                            <GridCol>
                                <button onClick={onConfirm}>Confirm</button>
                            </GridCol>
                        </GridRow>
                    }
                />
            </div>
        </Modal>
    );
};
```